# Can I flash the scrollbars on a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios4

As a UIWebView doesnt not inherit from UIScrollView it doesnt have the flashScrollIndicators method.

Is there a way to replicate this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  Not without digging around in undocumented subviews and exploring private APIs.  It's just not functionality that Apple, in their infinite wisdom, decided to expose.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```objectivec
[myWebView.scrollView flashScrollIndicators];
```

Comment: This is an old question, but perhaps it might help other people with that problem. If this call doesn't work, try `[myWebView.scrollView performSelector: @selector(flashScrollIndicators) withObject: nil afterDelay: 0];` instead.